# LightInject SignalR missing .RegisterHubs method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ioc-container, light-inject

I just started using LightInject for my MVC project and it's working just fine.
But i wanted to use it for my SignalR hubs too. So i followed the instructions at http://www.lightinject.net/#signalr. However i cannot see the method ServiceContainer.RegisterHubs anywhere. I have installed the LightInject, LightInject.Mvc and LightInject.SignalR dll's.

```
using log4net.Config;
using LightInject;
using Microsoft.Owin;   
using Owin;
using MvcProject;
using MvcProject.ApplicationServices.Interfaces.EventSignups;

[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof (Startup))]

namespace MvcProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
            var container = new ServiceContainer();
            container.Register<IEventSignupService>();
            container.Register<IViewModelRetrieverEventCommentService>();
            container.Register<IViewModelRetrieverEventService>();
            container.RegisterHubs(); //cannot see method

            app.MapSignalR(container.EnableSignalR());
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is just bad documentation. The method does not exist and never existed. You have to register each and every hub manually within your LightInject `Container`.

Also, be aware of [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489071/signalr-server-client-call-not-working) I've encountered by changing the `DependencyResolver` within SignalR for LightInject.

PS: I know my answer is late but still tought it could be useful for people searching for the same issue.